# JSF 2 dynamic generated ids not found

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, render

I have problem with dynamic generated ids in  f:ajax tag in render parameter. I get error:

```
Component with id:pak_Internet not found

viewId=/start.xhtml
location=C:\servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\tst-web-war\start.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
javax.faces.FacesException - Component with id:pak_Internet not found
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlAjaxBehaviorRenderer.getComponentId(HtmlAjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:411)
```

code:

```
<ui:repeat var="servicesPhones" value="#{cc.attrs.limits.servicesLimits}">  
            <h:selectOneMenu
                value="#{cc.attrs.limits.phoneSelected}">
                **<f:ajax render="pak_#{servicesPhones.name}" event="change" execute="@this"/>**
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.limits.getPhones(servicesPhones.name)}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:panelGroup id="pak_#{servicesPhones.name}">
                <ui:repeat var="pak" value="#{cc.attrs.limits.getPackages(servicesPhones.name)}">
                    #{pak.name}<br/>
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

Any idea how to resolved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove those EL expressions from the `id` attribtue. The `<ui:repeat>` will by itself already ensure the uniqueness of those IDs and already update the right one.

```
<f:ajax ... render="pak" />
...
<h:panelGroup id="pak">
```

If you used those EL expressions with the sole reason to be able to identify/select the JSF-generated HTML representation in JavaScript or CSS, then you'd need to look for an alternate approach via `styleClass`.